# SVG in Chrome is wider than SVG in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

My logo on my website is an inline SVG
And it works very well

But for some odd reason, Chrome is treading the SVG as if it has a width of 300px, but Firefox doesn't and shows the SVG correctly

So the result is, when using Chrome it adds a lot of empty space on both sides of the actual SVG content and centers it. 
Image can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGEaa.png) 
And all the HTML, CSS etc. is available here http://codepen.io/peterbrinck/pen/JYNPNp

Here's the SVG 
Maybe it's something obvious, and it's just because I don't know enough of SVG yet

```
<svg
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    version="1.1"
    id="roboto-svg"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 390.03581 103.1359"
    enable-background="new 0 0 841.9 595.3"
    xml:space="preserve"
    inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    sodipodi:docname="robot.svg"><metadata
    id="metadata27"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
        rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
        rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
    id="defs25" /><sodipodi:namedview
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#666666"
    borderopacity="1"
    objecttolerance="10"
    gridtolerance="10"
    guidetolerance="10"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0"
    inkscape:pageshadow="2"
    inkscape:window-width="1855"
    inkscape:window-height="1056"
    id="namedview23"
    showgrid="false"
    fit-margin-top="3"
    fit-margin-left="3"
    fit-margin-right="3"
    fit-margin-bottom="3"
    inkscape:zoom="1.4142136"
    inkscape:cx="-49.249423"
    inkscape:cy="172.6809"
    inkscape:window-x="65"
    inkscape:window-y="24"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1"
    inkscape:current-layer="Layer_1" /><path
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    d="m 45.717895,50.417894 c -9.3,-9.3 -24.3,-9.3 -33.6,0 v 40.6"
    id="path9"
    inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23579979;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10" /><circle
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    cx="455.10001"
    cy="312.70001"
    r="23.799999"
    id="circle15-7"
    sodipodi:cx="455.10001"
    sodipodi:cy="312.70001"
    sodipodi:rx="23.799999"
    sodipodi:ry="23.799999"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23600006;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10"
    transform="translate(-365.475,-245.56411)" /><circle
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    cx="385.20001"
    cy="312.70001"
    r="23.799999"
    id="circle11"
    sodipodi:cx="385.20001"
    sodipodi:cy="312.70001"
    sodipodi:rx="23.799999"
    sodipodi:ry="23.799999"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23600006;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10"
    transform="translate(-225.5821,-245.48211)" /><line
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    x1="135.81789"
    y1="67.217911"
    x2="135.81789"
    y2="12.1179"
    id="line13"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23579979;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10" /><circle
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    cx="455.10001"
    cy="312.70001"
    r="23.799999"
    id="circle15"
    sodipodi:cx="455.10001"
    sodipodi:cy="312.70001"
    sodipodi:rx="23.799999"
    sodipodi:ry="23.799999"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23600006;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10"
    transform="translate(-225.5821,-245.48211)" /><path
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    d="m 310.7179,84.017894 c -9.3,9.3 -24.3,9.3 -33.6,0 v -64.9"
    id="path17"
    inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23579979;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10" /><line
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    x1="277.11792"
    y1="43.417889"
    x2="301.11792"
    y2="43.417889"
    id="line19"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23579979;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10" /><circle
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    cx="579.70001"
    cy="312.70001"
    r="23.799999"
    id="circle21"
    sodipodi:cx="579.70001"
    sodipodi:cy="312.70001"
    sodipodi:rx="23.799999"
    sodipodi:ry="23.799999"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#39cccc;stroke-width:18.23579979;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10"
    transform="translate(-225.5821,-245.48211)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It probably has to do with the HTML/CSS showing the SVG. Probably related to the `display` property. Not enough code here to know for certain.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara
I've come to the conclusion, that it has something to do, with the way that Chrome resizes the SVG.

The SVG has a height of 40px, defined by CSS.

And then Chrome resizes the content of the SVG, instead of the whole element.

If I remove the height, it works, but then it's too big.

Comment: This will have nothing to do with the SVG itself, it will be related to how you are you have styled the svg element and/or its container.  We really need to see your HTML/CSS to answer your question.

Comment: Here's all the HTML and CSS that affects the SVG
http://codepen.io/peterbrinck/pen/JYNPNp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out

It has something to do with the aspect ratio
When in the SVG, width="100%" is set, Chrome keeps the aspect ratio in a weird way, instead of resizing the whole SVG element, it just resizes the content of the SVG, according to the height that's set with CSS

Comment: You might want to post your HTML and CSS above so other SO users can see your question in context with your answer